# Prove the following function is decreasing

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Given:
$E[u(t)] = \int_{\Omega} \left(\frac{1}{2}\left|\nabla u\right|^{2} - \frac{1}{4}u^{4}\right)dx$, and $u_{t} - \nabla u = u^{3}$.

Show: $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}E\left[u(t)\right] \le 0$.

$\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $u=0$ on $\partial \Omega$ and $u(x,0) = u_{0}(x)$ and $E[u_{0}(x)] < 0$

I get this far using integration by parts:
$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}E\left[u(t)\right] = -\int_{\Omega} \Delta u \cdot u_{t} - \int_{\Omega} u^{3} \cdot u_{t}$.
I think this can now be represented as a steepest descent:
$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}E\left[u(t)\right] = <u_{t}, -\nabla E[u(t)]>$.
Combined with the initial condition, I think this may give the desired result, but I do not know enough about "steepest descent" to be certain.

Comment: Are you sure its is $u_t-\nabla u=u^3$? Maybe it is $u_t-\Delta u=u^3$?

Comment: As Tomás also wrote, it *has* to be $-\Delta u$ instead of $-\nabla u$; otherwise the dimensions of the objects being summed don't even match. And once this is the case, the result is obvious form your work.

Answer (score 0):

No need to talk about steepest descent: it's just that 
$$
\frac{dE}{dt} = - \int_{\Omega} u_t\cdot (\Delta u+u^3) = -\int_{\Omega} u_t^2 \le 0
$$

(I don't write $\frac{\partial  E}{\partial t}$ here because in my mind, $E$ is a function of one variable $t$ only. It's true that $u$ is involved, but for one thing $u$ is fixed, and for another, we would not be writing $\frac{\partial  E}{\partial u}$ anyway: it's not like $u$ is another variable on par  with $t$.)